# Not able to give vertical margin using offset in Flutter JustToolTip widget

Tags: flutter

I am using using `just_the_tooltip` package to show tooltip and the code is as follows :

```
        JustTheTooltip(
          triggerMode: TooltipTriggerMode.tap,
          preferredDirection: AxisDirection.right,
            offset: 2,
          tailBaseWidth: 25,
          tailLength: 15,
          elevation: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 28),
          content: Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12, vertical: 8),
            child: Text(
              toolTipText,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                color: Colors.white,
                height: 1.8,
                decoration: TextDecoration.none,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: const MouseRegion(
              cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
              child: Icon(Icons.info_outline, color: Colors.green)),
        ),
```

The issue is like the tooltip is touching the Appbar in the flutter web due the behaviour of the overlay, but now i want to give some vertical margin to the tooltip somehow. Unfortunately the offset property only works with the horizontal margin but not for vertical.

if there is anything that will add some margin to the top of the tooltip please let me know.